# pg_search pg_search_scope poor performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I've a product model with a title string column that i have copied into an indexed tvector column .

here is my pg_search implemtation in the model file :

```
class Product
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_by_title, against: :title,
    using:{
      tsearch: {
        dictionary: 'simple',
        prefix: true,
        tsvector_column: 'tsv'
      }
}
end
```

here is the query produced  by `Product.search_by_title('windo')`:

```
SELECT "products".* 
FROM "products" 
INNER JOIN (SELECT "products"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank(("products"."tsv"), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'windo' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS rank FROM "products" WHERE ((("products"."tsv") @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'windo' || ' ''' || ':*'))))
) AS pg_search_0a3e27b8ca818264d75c8d ON "products"."id" = pg_search_0a3e27b8ca818264d75c8d.pg_search_id  
ORDER BY pg_search_0a3e27b8ca818264d75c8d.rank DESC, "products"."id" ASC
```

This join query is messing my perf :-(, why isn't `pg_search` building such a query :

```
SELECT "products".*, (ts_rank(("products"."tsv"), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'wind' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS rank 
FROM "products" 
WHERE ((("products"."tsv") @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'wind' || ' ''' || ':*'))))
ORDER BY rank DESC, "products"."id" ASC
```

... which is 100 times faster, What am i missing ?

thx for the help !